# How to Structure Categories to be Subfields of a Page?

Tags: wordpress, organization, wp-list-categories

So I have a page structure in place that looks like this:

- Restaurant

  - Restaurant Name 1
  - Restaurant Name 2
  - Restaurant Name 3
- Teams
- Jobs

So the Teams is basically a Category Archive page that lists posts that are tagged as "teams". Is there a way so I could have each team post associate with either Restaurant 1, 2 or 3 without manually adding them as a subcategory?

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up a Custom Field titled "Related Restaurant", and then fill out the value with the slug or ID of the restaurant you want to associate with. Then you would grab the data from within the Team post like so:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Related Restaurant', true); ?>
```

I'm not sure how exactly you would want to utilize this data, so what you do with it is entirely up to you.